# ASP.NET MVC: Customization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Which section of ASP.NET MVC should be overrided to be able to change the name of fields (Model Properties) in output to a custom things? Something like below:

```
<input id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" />
```

to this:

```
<input id="MYCUSTOMFORMAT-IsActive" name="MYCUSTOMFORMAT-IsActive" type="checkbox" />
```

This custom formatting shouldn't break down anything such client-side and server-side validation.

Thanks in advance ;)

**More Info**

I know that we can do this in Display/Editor Templates but i think this will cause infringement.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the name in the HtmlAttributes parameter of the Html.TextBoxFor (etc) helper methods - such as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.FirstName, new {id = "customId_originalId"})
```

However  since you are changing this on the client side, the server side will not be able to recognize these changed names and will not bind properly unless you write your own model binder. As such it probably isn't aware of the server side validations to link this to either so again you are stuck handling this in a custom rolled manner.

Comment: Thanks Adam, Can you explain this a bit more? or provide article, blog post link?

Comment: Which part? For custom attributes search for htmlattributes mvc  ex. http://michaelware.net/post/2010/01/31/Custom-Attributes-When-Using-HtmlTextBoxFor.aspx   any parameter you specify in the new {XXX ="yyy"}   xxx will be the html attribute to render out. If you specify id, the control will get whatever id you enter. to override the css class, you actually need to use @class since "class" is a reserved word. For model binder - lots out there - one here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/02/25/asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Adam, Actually my question is last paragraph of @Chao answer "How to handle translating names to properties and vice versa"

Comment: if you mean his part on model binders - you still have the issue of not only server side model binding, but also then tying in server side validations.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround for this if you want a constant prefix, but not necessarily the right way to do things, would be to use a viewmodel that contains your properties. in this case:

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    CustomViewModel MYCUSTOMFORMAT = new CustomViewModel();
    return View(MYCUSTOMFORMAT);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(CustomViewModel MYCUSTOMFORMAT){
    return View(MYCUSTOMFORMAT);
}
```

This will give you an Id of MYCUSTOMFORMAT.IsActive.

The proper way to do this would likely be overriding the default model binder and how it handles translating names to properties but I don't know model binders well enough to give you much direction on this.

Comment: OK, But your approach isn't very good. There are a lot of dirty coding by your way.

Comment: As I said, a simple work around but not the right way. I don't have more information on his needs and sometimes (especially if only needed once or twice) the simple workaround is good enough. The alternative, digging pretty deep into custom model binders, is the right way but depending on needs might be overkill.